# Clear all forms on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, document-ready, domready

I want to clear all forms on page load. I tried to use this function on domready, but it doesn't help. I'm new to JavaScript. Is there anything wrong with this function?

```
   $(':input', form)
 .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
 .val('')
 .removeAttr('checked')
 .removeAttr('selected');
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try using the plain javascript `reset` method on a form

```
$('form').each(function() { this.reset() });
```

This should reset each form to its default state.

To re-enable all checkboxes, you can try:

```
$(':checkbox').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: I have other function that limits checkbox amount in 1 of forms. I tried this code within domready. But after refresh i see that there is no selected checkbox BUT ALL PREVIOUSLY DISABLED (BY jQ SCRIPT) CHECKBOXES ARE STILL DISABLED  `$("input[type=checkbox][name=subjects]").click(function() {

    var bol = $("input[type=checkbox][name=subjects]:checked").length >= 3;     
    $("input[type=checkbox][name=subjects]").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);

});`

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu It sounds like you will need to write a custom reset method that will undo these modifications.

Comment: Then help me to reset and re-enable theese checkboxes

Comment: Finally:)) Thx code looks like that: `$('form').each(function() { this.reset() });
$(':checkbox').prop('disabled', false);` Edit your answer if you want. Also upvote my Q ))

Answer (score 2):

maybe this is what your asking? not sure why you would need it. the fields should be blank on page load anyways.  you should change the values php side.

```
$('input[type=text]').val('');
$('input[type=radio]').checked=false;
$('input[type=checkbox]').checked=false;
```

or maybe even

```
$("input:not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')").val('').checked=false;
```

Comment: Maybe text inputs always clear, but radio button, checkboxes not. That's why I wanna reset all forms on page load

Comment: I have other function that limits checkbox amount in 1 of forms. I tried this code within domready. But after refresh i see that there is no selected checkbox BUT ALL PREVIOUSLY DISABLED (BY jQ SCRIPT) CHECKBOXES ARE STILL DISABLED  `$("input[type=checkbox][name=subjects]").click(function() {

    var bol = $("input[type=checkbox][name=subjects]:checked").length >= 3;     
    $("input[type=checkbox][name=subjects]").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);

});`

Answer (score 0):

I would give each control i wanted to clear a class name of say `class="ClearOnStartup"` and then my jQuery would be;

```
$(function(){
  $(".ClearOnStartup").val("");
});
```

I'd have a different one for check boxes only because I like to seperate things like this into batches.

try this for checkboxes

```
$('.ClearOnStartup').attr('checked', false);
```

There is probably a better way tho

Comment: i don't want to add extra class just because of form clear. There must be other way,